# Local free $\mathcal{O}_X$module and free $\mathcal{O}_X$ module

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As we all know,if X is connected,then the rank of local free $\mathcal{O}_X$module $\mathcal{F}$ is constant.

We call it invertible if it has rank one.

But by glueing sheaves on hartshorne exercise 1.22 on page 69, it is unique.    Is every local free $\mathcal{O}_X$ module $\mathcal{F}$ which has constant rank free?

Thank you!

Comment: I think this is not true,but I can not find the problem.

Comment: this is true if $X$ is reduced scheme i.e a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$ mod  $\mathcal{F}$ of finite constant rank over a reduced scheme is locally free.

Comment: @user2902293 what? $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\Bbb P^1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @user2902293 as far as I can tell, that's not the question, though - the OP asks if every locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$ module with constant rank is free (which is false as indicated in my first comment). Perhaps I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Also my comment does not answer your question. @KReiser mentions a counterexample to your question.

Comment: @user2902293 why can't we use Glueing sheaves?where the problem can be found?

Comment: @Sky, i do not understand what you mean by it is unique by Glueing sheaves. Given a bunch of sheaves on open cover of a scheme and isomorphisms among their intersections you can glue the sheaves to get a unique(upto isomorphism) extension.  What this allows you to deduce is that if you had a connected space then it is inevitable that the rank of a locally free sheaf must be same which is only due to the fact that pairwise intersections on any open cover must intersect.

Comment: @Sky your question is equivalent to the following on affine schemes. On a commutative ring with $1$, is every projective module $M$ of constant rank (this makes sense since localisation of projective module is free at a prime) free.

Comment: @user2902293  let me think $F\mid_{U_i} \backsimeq O_X \mid _{U_i}$.     And $F\mid_{U_i\bigcap U_j}=F\mid_{U_i \bigcap U_j}$,so I think $ O_X \backsimeq F$ by glueing sheaves.         Now I think they are isomorphic as sheaves,but not as schemes . Is this true?

Comment: @user2902293 I think you need $M$ is finite presentation

Comment: Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf such that $\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}\xrightarrow{\phi_i} \mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i}$ then it does not follow, in general, that $\mathcal{F}\cong \mathcal{O}_X$. This is because on $U_i\cap U_j$ there is incompatibility of isomorphisms. Indeed, given a section of $\mathcal{F}$ on $U_i\cap U_j$ you can identify it as a section of $\mathcal{O}_X$ on $U_i\cap U_j$ via the isomorphism $\phi_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}$ or via the isomorphism $\phi_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}$  but they need not be same. The glueing condition on sheaves is precisely that it shouldnt matter which isomorphismyou choose.

Comment: @Sky Indeed you are right I should require $M$ to be of finite presentation but it is enough to assume that $M$ is finitely generated since finitely generated and projective implies finitely presented.

Comment: @Sky I am sorry this discussion is getting big. We can move to chat if you wish.

Comment: @user2902293 no problem,thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60258/discussion-between-user2902293-and-sky).